# Nav Mesh runs away from player instead of towards player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class enemyFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NavMeshAgent enemy;
    public Transform Player;

    void Update()
    {
        enemy.SetDestination(Player.position);
    }
}
```

This is my code. I followed the tutorial perfectly and I don't know why the nav mesh runs in the exact opposite direction. I have tried to research but all the questions online ask how to make the nav mesh run away. Can you please help?

Comment: Have you changed the scale of the GameObject which has the NavMeshAgent component?  You can get odd behaviour if the scale is something other than 1.

Comment: Or if you  parent or unparent the area with the navmesh.

Comment: Do you have scenery? Try a scene with a simple plane and no other scenery objects, navmesh it and see what happens. Also, check your navmesh setting and agent settings on each navmeshagent controlled object.